# Generate Method with correct signature as expected from Functional interface in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, functional-interface

I am using Java 8 functional interfaces a lot.

In particular, I have some methods that register functions with certain signatures. Its signature is as follows:

```
<A extends IA, D extends IB, B extends IB> void registerRConv(Class<A> tA, Class<D> tD, Class<B> tB,
        BiFunction<A, D, B> ad2b);
```

*Sidenote: in case you're wondering, its a converter registry that registers, which types are converted to which, and a function which does the actual convertig*

I use this method quite often, and everytime i find myself typing

```
registry.registerRConv(Common.Choice.class, Choice.class, Object.class, Converter::getChoice)
```

Where the given classes all exist, but the static method - `Converter::getChoice` in the example - does not yet exist.

Now, if i do this in IntelliJ IDE's, when i press alt+Enter I get an option to automatically create that method in the current class - with the expected signature.

Can I make Eclipse do this? and if so, how?

Comment: suppose you have some features in Eclipse with this. just right click on the source fie -> Refactor and you have Extract Interface, etc.

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse for a while, but I remember that pressing `Ctrl+1` presented a menu with context-aware options, where the option to create the missing method was one of the topmost ones.

Comment: Which eclipse Version do you use?

Comment: Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers, Neon.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of change that is provided by "quick fixes" invoked by pressing `Ctrl+1`.

Unfortunately, when the resolve error is reported against a method reference expression, the existing quick fix is not offered.

I filed https://bugs.eclipse.org/516504 to address this.

In the meanwhile, the workaround would be:

- Change the method reference to a lambda expression
- Invoke the quick fix to create the missing method
- Invoke the quick assist "Convert to method reference" (`Ctrl+1` also here)

Comment: I don't see the "Convert to method reference" in the last step. All I get is this: http://pasteboard.co/5cz6pqdaQ.png

Comment: Oh nvm, my fault - i think i misunderstood your instructions.

Comment: However, in the second step, Eclipse creates a method with the return type Object which is incorrect